# Geofence does not work in Android devices

Tags: codenameone

I am developing an iOS and Android app using a geofence to identify if players are or are not on the courts. It is working fine in iOs but it does not work at all in android.

it is pretty much the same as the Geofence Class example with calling and API to register entered and exited.

```
public class GeofenceListenerImpl implements GeofenceListener {

    public static String API = "https://xxxxxx.com/xxxxxx/";

    @Override
    public void onExit(String id) {


        Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {
            String textID =id;
            String username, courtID, primaryCourt, primaryCourtText, userNickName, courtName ;

            ConnectionRequest courtExitRequest = new ConnectionRequest();
            // Format ID ---> (USERNAME)___COURT___(PRIMARYCOURT 0=false 1 = true)
            username = textID.substring(0,textID.indexOf("___"));
            textID = textID.substring(textID.indexOf("___")+3);
            courtID = textID.substring(0,textID.indexOf("___"));
            textID = textID.substring(textID.indexOf("___")+3);
            primaryCourtText = textID.substring(0,textID.indexOf("___"));
            primaryCourt = (primaryCourtText.trim().contains("1")) ? "true" : "false" ;
            textID = textID.substring(textID.indexOf("___")+3);
            courtName = textID.substring(0,textID.indexOf("___"));
            textID = textID.substring(textID.indexOf("___")+3);
            userNickName = textID.trim();


            Date now =  new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
            courtExitRequest.setUrl(API + "xxxxxxxxx/playeroutcourt");
            courtExitRequest.setPost(false);
            courtExitRequest.addArgument("username", username);
            courtExitRequest.addArgument("courtid", courtID);
            courtExitRequest.addArgument("isprimarycourt", primaryCourt);
            courtExitRequest.addArgument("timeStamp", now.toString());
            courtExitRequest.setFailSilently(true);
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(courtExitRequest);

            if (Display.getInstance().isMinimized()) {

                LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
                n.setId("geo-Exit-01");
                n.setAlertBody("Great job out there. Wishing you all the best!");
                n.setAlertTitle("See you later " + userNickName);
                n.setAlertSound("/notification_sound_beep-01a.mp3");
                // alert sound file name must begin with notification_sound

                Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
                        n,
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 1000), // fire date/time
                        LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE  // Whether to repeat and what frequency
                );
            } else {

                WP_message.generalMessage("\uE766", "See you later " + userNickName + "\n\n" + "Great job out there. Wishing you all the best!");

            }

        });




    }

    @Override

    public void onEntered(String id) {

        Display.getInstance().callSerially(() -> {

            String textID = id;
            String username, courtID, primaryCourt, primaryCourtText, userNickName, courtName ;

            ConnectionRequest courtExitRequest = new ConnectionRequest();

            // Format ID ---> (USERNAME)___COURT___(PRIMARYCOURT 0=false 1 = true)

            username = textID.substring(0,textID.indexOf("___"));
            textID = textID.substring(textID.indexOf("___")+3);
            courtID = textID.substring(0,textID.indexOf("___"));
            textID = textID.substring(textID.indexOf("___")+3);
            primaryCourtText = textID.substring(0,textID.indexOf("___"));
            primaryCourt = (primaryCourtText.trim().contains("1")) ? "true" : "false" ;
            textID = textID.substring(textID.indexOf("___")+3);
            courtName = textID.substring(0,textID.indexOf("___"));
            textID = textID.substring(textID.indexOf("___")+3);
            userNickName = textID.trim();

            Date now =  new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

            courtExitRequest.setUrl(API + "xxxxxxxxx/playerincourt");
            courtExitRequest.setPost(false);
            courtExitRequest.addArgument("username", username);
            courtExitRequest.addArgument("courtid", courtID);
            courtExitRequest.addArgument("isprimarycourt", primaryCourt);
            courtExitRequest.addArgument("timeStamp", now.toString());
            courtExitRequest.setFailSilently(true);
            NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueue(courtExitRequest);


            if (Display.getInstance().isMinimized()) {


                LocalNotification n = new LocalNotification();
                n.setId("geo-Entered-01");
                n.setAlertBody( userNickName + "! Good luck with your games!");
                n.setAlertTitle("Welcome to " + courtName);
                n.setAlertSound("/notification_sound_beep-01a.mp3");
                // alert sound file name must begin with notification_sound

                Display.getInstance().scheduleLocalNotification(
                        n,
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + (60 * 1000), // fire date/time
                        LocalNotification.REPEAT_NONE  // Whether to repeat and what frequency
                );

            } else {
                WP_message.generalMessage("\uEA22", "Welcome to " + courtName + "\n\n" + userNickName + "! Good luck with your games!");
            }

        });

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried to change the permission for Android but it does not work using the Hint and manifest.

Comment: Which Android version are you using? Did you try with an older device to see if this is a device specific issue? 
Try using Mock location and looking at the logcat output to see if there's any applicable printouts.

Comment: Hey @shai-almog, thanks for answering me, I have tested with 3 Samsung models Note 5, Mini Galaxy 5, and Galaxy 8.

Comment: If this is happening with older devices then it's probably an issue in the code. Did you try mock location and looking at the logcat output?

Comment: @ShaiAlmog Thank you for supporting me. I implemented a push notification that allowed me to reduce the GeoFence class to only send a RESTful API Call. Apple is working amazingly. However, the issue is still in Android.  
I am new to Logcat so please bear with me. Please, let me know if the following information helps. 

1. The app always crashed or closed when the phone is locked. 
2. When I debug the GeoFence creation process the class Handler is partially accessed. 
3. Error in Android Studio Call requires API level 29 (current min is 19): `checkBackgroundLocationPermission`

Comment: Accessing hidden field Landroid/app/job/JobService;->mEngine:Landroid/app/job/JobServiceEngine; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)

Comment: Not sure about this. Let me check.

Comment: There seems to be a regression related to this functionality. We're looking into this. I suggest filing an issue to keep track of this at https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/

Comment: Early this morning I updated Codename One to the new version 7.0.104. The Geofence in Andriod is working now. I feel like it behaves a little differently than on iOS. I will keep testing to see if I should may little changes or not. 

Thank you so much for supporting my project! I am very happy and excited.